# how to save array in mongodb, which node-twitter and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, mongoose

Tell them which the problem is.

As you can see, I use the [module node-twitter](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/blob/master/README.md) to collect all the tweets for a given user but I need to save every tweet or all the array, at a base data nosql as mongo. My code not work, it's wrong! i don't know , which is problem, thanks for you answers

```
var Twitter     = require('twitter')
,   mongoose    = require('mongoose')
,   db          = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tweets')
,   tweetSchema = new db.Schema({
        texto:    new Array(),
}),     util = require('util');

Twitter.get('/statuses/user_timeline/37503675.json', {include_entities:true}, function(data) {
    var otro = new Array()
    ,   test = db.model('tweetin', tweetSchema);
    // iteration for all tweet in user id 37503675
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        otro.push(util.inspect(data[i].text));
    };
    // create
    var testtest = new test({
        texto: otro
    });
    //save in mongo 
    testtest.save(function (err) {if (err) console.log ('Error on save!')});
    //disconnected
    // with db.disconnect(); or without 
});
```

Comment: It looks like you are disconnecting from the database before your save function is called back.

Comment: I understand what you say, try it without disconnecting but not saved, and in log the mongodb, not register activity

Comment: `otro` is already an array and I think that is what you are trying to save so don't wrap it inside another array `texto: otro`

Comment: I try, but not work! thanks for you answer

Comment: Do you call `db.disconnect()` at any time? Have you tried to wrap it inside the `.save` callback function? Also it would be nice to have some console logging and mongo log output pasted in question. By the way... try too to define model outside the `Twitter.get` callback. The model registration may end async to the `.save` method call.